# Bulk update attributes or assign source error

Tags: products, bulk

Magento 2.4.3-p1

When performing bulk attribute updates or when assigning or unassigning stock sources, we get following error. Not sure why it's behaving like this, any ideas?

```
    TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Model\BulkSessionProductsStorage::getProductsSkus() must be of the type array, null returned in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui/Model/BulkSessionProductsStorage.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Source/BulkAssignPost.php(137): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Model\BulkSessionProductsStorage->getProductsSkus()
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost->execute()
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->___callParent()
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/InventoryCatalogAdminUi/Controller/Adminhtml/Source/BulkAssignPost/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->execute()
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->___callParent()
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/InventoryCatalogAdminUi/Controller/Adminhtml/Source/BulkAssignPost/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Controller\Adminhtml\Source\BulkAssignPost\Interceptor->dispatch()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#24 {main}
```

**BulkSessionProductsStorage.php**

```
 /**
     * Get selected product SKUs
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductsSkus(): array
    {
        return $this->session->getProductSkus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused when bulk updating a lot of products, to the point where the admin session runs out of space.
If that's the case, you should see something like the following line in system.log:

```
main.WARNING: Session size of 765625 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000.
```

A workaround is to set the max size to unlimited (or high enough that it can complete the task), the following sets it to unlimited:

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0
```

Alternatively, it can be set through the admin interface (https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-session-management.html):

> Store > Settings > Configuration
> expand Advanced and choose System.
> Expand the Security section to access the session settings.
> Enter new session size(s) in bytes.